# Allowing a Dynamic Proxy to cast to any compatible interface. Regardless

Tags: java, casting, dynamic-proxy

I made a Dynamic Proxy to be the middle man when handling specific methods in a class. I'm doing this to avoid having to override every single method in each of the interfaces that I need to take control of.

#### Waffley bit that nobody will understand or care about (but may add more context to the question):

In the example I am going to give, I've tried to make it generic so you can compile it to test and run yourself, but in the real situation, I have something like this:

```
interface CommandSender

interface ConsoleCommandSender extends CommandSender
interface Player extends CommandSender
```

If I were to make a proxy of a `ConsoleCommandSender` instance, the resulting proxy SHOULD be castable to a `CommandSender`. In reality, `ConsoleCommandSender` doesn't list all of its interfaces with `getInterfaces()` and this happens:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy18 cannot be cast to org.bukkit.command.CommandSender`

The Player class does not have this issue, and is always castable to `CommandSender`.

#### The real question:

So, using the following code as a starting point, how can one successfully cast the proxy denoted by `myProxy` to the format desired without having to worry about the `ClassCastException`?

The following code will successfully compile and run, but hopefully you understand what I'm getting at by casting to a `List` rather than an `ArrayList`.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProxyClass implements InvocationHandler {

    private Object classProxy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example declaration
        // (I know the proxy should really be cast as an ArrayList
        // but this is my point, it SHOULD work anyway)
        ArrayList methodObject = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> myProxy = (List<String>)ProxyClass.newInstance(methodObject, false);

        // Example usage
        myProxy.add("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(myProxy.get(0));
    }

    public static Object newInstance(Object proxy, boolean silent) {
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                proxy.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                proxy.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                new ProxyClass(proxy));
    }

    private ProxyClass(Object proxy) {
        this.classProxy = proxy;
    }

    // Is called whenever a method is invoked
    public Object invoke(Object p, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        return m.invoke(classProxy, args);
    }

}
```

On another thread I made about the preliminary part of this issue, one guy commented saying I could use the `<T>` variable to add another valid interface to the list. I didn't really understand how to implement this though, but it seemed like a good start.

Comment: Could you show us the code which is failing. I try using the code provided and adaptating it using CommandSender and so on. Even if the getInterfaces does not return the CommandSender interface, the proxy instance is casted and method is well executed.

Comment: Two options, you can either use the GitHub project here: https://github.com/zonedabone/CommandSigns (See src/org/zonedabone/commandsigns/CommandSignsMessagingProxy) or I can recreate a small project that will force this error.

The problem is that you can only see this error when the project is being used as a Bukkit Plugin.

Comment: You can also check out my previous post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652663/casting-proxies-getting-classcastexception/

Comment: @CJxD - looks like he did. I was sure this is his problem to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I admit I understood your question -
You want to be able to "directly" cast to ArrayList? I mean -

> ```
>     ArrayList<String> myProxy = (ArrayList<String>)ProxyClass.newInstance(methodObject, false);
> ```

This just won't work for you. The reason is that the generated object is not an instant of ArrayList. In a sense the behavior resembles decorator. 
Is decorator an instance of the object it decorates? No, they conform to the same interface. 
What you should do is consider using [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/). 
CGLIB let's you create proxies (intercepted objects) for classes.
 a Proxied object by CGBLib is indeed an instance of the proxied object. 
If I remember correctly, Hibernate uses CGLib and ASM in order to proxy the entity objects, 
You can see [here](https://github.com/voider/tests/tree/master/yair) a link to some experiments I did with CGLIB.

Comment: It's not directly casting to ArrayList that's the problem at all - it's just trying to cast to an interface of the proxied object. However, I'll take a look at CGLIB if it's not overly bulky.

Comment: Go ahead and take a look at the code I wrote. Took me around 15 minutes to get the hang of it.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/voider/tests/blob/master/yair/src/main/java/org/ovirt/test/TransactionProxy.java - you will see the invokeSuper usage there, that provides you another "hint" that a proxied class by CGLib extends the original one.